# how ECS awslogs works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm curious how it works using awslogs driver. At [Enabling the awslogs Log Driver for Your Containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html) section, it only mentioned setup logConfiguration using logDriver: awslogs. It indeed works out of box, but when you check the Docker Daemon on the box Docker is not using awslogs driver. So, how it works?

```
$ docker info | grep "Logging"
Logging Driver: json-file
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that [it is being passed as an argument to the run command for each instance of the container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-logging-driver-for-a-container). I have the opposite issue -- and am finding it difficult to override a request to build a container from docker-machine that is passing in `json-file` as the log driver.

To verify this, you can use `docker inspect` on a given container. It will have a field for `log driver` that will indicate what log driver it was started with. The `docker info` command you are using just tells you the default for the docker service.

However, if you do the docker inspect and it also says `json-file`, then there's probably something pulling the logs off the disk and into cloudwatch.